# How to control landline telephone from computer?

Tags: phone-call, telephony

I want to call other telephone number from my landline telephone using my computer. For example, I want to develop a software by C# or nodejs or any other programming language, which will have a textbox and a button. when I press the button it will call number in the textbox using my telephone, but I will use my telephone to talk, not any headphones. I just want to place the call by programming. Is it possible to achieve this?

N.B: I will use modem or pbx if I need to but don't know which way I should achieve this.

Comment: Which phone do you have? Does it expose any control connection?

Comment: this is a requirement. I think different user will have different type of phone. I don't know much about landline telephones, I need the concept. I don't know why people give down vote! is it my bad english or it's my fault that I don't know anything about telephone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with modems. That old things, which was used in dial up connections. 
Or VoIP and softphone, to run calls from software, not hardware phone.

Comment: thank you for your response. bye the way those modem have SDK to control from code? the phone should work without turning on pc but someone should be able to call from pc when they use their pc. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The modems can be controlled thru windows in easy way. There was dialer interface in old windows. I think it's still exist in win10.
Also most of modems has two ports phone IN and phone OUT to connect phone after modem..